# Cannot locate Package

Tags: package-management, software-installation

Whenever I type an application that could be installed into the terminal it says this is not installed yet, type: `sudo apt-get install [application]`. When I do this it says cannot locate package. Am I supposed to make my own package?

I am a total novice and have no idea what's going on. I've looked around for things but I can't work it out, figured I'd just ask.

Comment: Do you have some internet connection?

Comment: What package are you trying to install?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find it maybe you've done a clean install and haven't done an update yet, so do the following:

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install [application]

If that doesn't work update your question with what happens. Also specify what package you are trying to install.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Software Center(type Software Software Center in dash) and click on "Edit" on the menu bar(point your mouse on the menu bar for the menus to appear) and click on Software sources.

[image: Change source to "Main server"]

Change your source to "Main server" and then type the following command on a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then install your application using

```
sudo apt-get install [application_name]
```

Post the errors, if you get any, at any point of time during this process. This should work, by the way, without any problems.